# How do you get someones Twitter profile picture on Meteor?

Tags: twitter, meteor

I'm doing a project using Meteor. People can log in with Twitter. I was wondering if there was a way to get someones profile picture from Twitter in the Accounts.onCreateUser. Here's what I have in mine :

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

   var twitterInfo =  user.services.twitter;

   if (options.profile){

        options.profile.createdAt = new Date();//now!
        options.profile.twitterId = twitterInfo.id;
        options.profile.username = twitterInfo.screenName;
        options.profile.name  = options.profile.name;
        user.profile = options.profile; 
   }

    return user;
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the API (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/%3Ascreen_name) add this in:

```
options.profile.display_picture="http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/"+twitterInfo.screenName;
```

This was the traditional way, in api 1.1 its slightly harder (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners):

You need to get `GET users/show` and parse the `user` object for `profile_image_url`

Comment: api 1.0 is deprecated and no longer available.

Comment: I have also mentioned how to use 1.1, you need to get `/users/show` and get out `profile_image_url` from the user object. You need to OAuth first and use the token to make the request

Answer (score 6):

with twitter api 1.0 deprecation. the accepted answer is no longer valid.

```
Meteor.user().services.twitter.profile_image_url
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've added the Meteor packages **accounts-ui** and **accounts-twitter** to my app.
http://docs.meteor.com/#accountsui
These packages add Twitter OAuth login capability really easily.

Better still: I can access the current user via `Meteor.user()` from anywhere. 
And even better, they come they're own templates. So I can just use
`{{services.twitter.screenName}}` anywhere in my app to get the users twitter handle. 
`{{services.twitter.profile_image_url}}` for the avatar image url. And
`{{profile.name}}` for the Twitter username.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in with twitter URL's for the profile pic is being set in the Users collection at `services.twitter.profile_image_url and` `services.twitter.profile_image_url_https` so you could just read out those URL's.

I use the following line to set a users twitter profile pic in the profile object, which is visible to the client by default:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.userId()}, {$set {"profile.twitterpic":user.services.twitter.profile_image_url}});
```